# Wrapping <pre> inside table cell

Tags: html, css, css-tables, word-wrap, pre

I have some data in a set of pre tags who's inner text I want to wrap. I am achieving this with the following CSS:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

However, if I put the pre tags into a table cell, this no longer works; the data all stays on the one line.

I am aware that there is the white-space: pre-wrap option, however I am using this CSS in a WebBrowser control in C#, and it always render as IE7 would, and the pre-wrap property never appears to work.

Has anyone got any idea how I can get my CSS for the pre tags to work inside a table cell? Or whether it is even possible?

I am open to suggestions of alternatives to using a table, however I need to replicate a table in the sense of having rows with multiple cells, each of which will grow in height to match the largest one.

Comment: What `table-layout` does the table have?

Comment: @Pumbaa80 - no table-layout is defined for it, so I guess it'll be whatever default the browser assigns.

Comment: Then try `table-layout: fixed` to trigger the *other* table layout algorithm. With widths on your `thead > th`.

Comment: @FelipeAls - I just gave this a try, and can confirm it is allowing the pre content to wrap now, however I am unable to set the widths as the first two columns need to auto size horizontally, and the third column needs to just fill the rest of the page

Comment: Would `width: 100%` on the table element do that for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine figured a way around this, it isn't the cleanest of solutions but was sufficient for my problem.

The solution was to take the blank spaces and replace them with alternations of   and  as IE supports the wbr tag, it simulated the wrapping of text in a pre tag.

Hope this helps anyone else who runs into the issue!